# I build sentry but can't find `sentry.css` and `app.js`?

Tags: sentry

I run this:

1. git clone https://github.com/getsentry/sentry
2. python setup.py develop

It seems all ok, but when I access sentry from browser, 404 appends on sentry.css.

what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The 'setup.py develop' process is responsible for generating static media on demand when needed. Is it possible its failing? You can also run 'python setup.py build_static' to run it again. You'll need npm 0.12.x or newer for it to function.

Comment: `setup.py develop` return sucess, and build_static told me already built.. and there is node and npm. I resolved this by run `./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js -c webpack.conf.js` , this command return an error of `can't found modules fs`, so I `npm i fs` and rerun webpack, sentry.css and app.js appeared.  Thanks.